# Extract top 10 biggest files from tar archive Linux

Tags: linux, file, extract, tar

I want to extract only the top 10 biggest files from a tar archive using Linux terminal. I can insert the path of the files to be extracted, but I want to know if I can do it using a command to sort the files so I can extract only the 10 biggest of them.

`tar -xvf myfile.tar | sort -n -r | head -n 2 > otherfile` (in this way I only succeeded to save the names of the files, not the files..)

Can you please help or advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below commands to actually extract only the top 10 biggest files from a tar.

```
files=$(tar -tvf <tar-name> |sort -n -r |egrep -v "^d"|head | awk '{print $9}')
tar -xvf <tar-name> $files
```

Let me explain what it's doing exactly :

This command will list archive contents to stdout.

```
tar -tvf <tar-name>
```

This will sort the content.

```
tar -tvf <tar-name> |sort -n -r
```

This will exlcude the directories if any :

```
tar -tvf <tar-name> |sort -n -r |egrep -v "^d"
```

This will print the top 10 files (head by default prints 10):

```
tar -tvf <tar-name> |sort -n -r |egrep -v "^d"|head
```

This will fetch only the filenames :

```
tar -tvf <tar-name> |sort -n -r |egrep -v "^d"|head | awk '{print $9}'
```

Once we get the filenames, we save it in files variable and then we can use below command to fetch the exact files from the tarball :

```
tar -xvf <tar-name> $files
```

Comment: Per the [GNU `tar` Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) `tar` can accept multiple arguments and in this case extract multiple files in one pass.  You should be able to do `tar -xvf ... $files`.  Note that multiple passes through a *large* `tar` archive can be rather slow.  Note also that if you know there's a large disparity in file sizes in a `tar` archive so that the top 10 largest files make up a large percentage of the total size of the archive - like 80 or 90% - it's likely faster to just extract the whole thing in one pass.