# Extract 3 smallest files from Tar archive in descending order by size

Tags: linux, file, extract, tar

How can I extract from a Tar file in Linux the 3 smallest files in descending order using command line?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917340/extract-top-10-biggest-files-from-tar-archive-linux. It's almost same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the file details, sort by size, pick the top3 files, build the `tar x` command, and execute to extract the 3 files:

```
 tar tvf foo.tar
       |awk '$0=$3"\x99"$NF'
       |sort -n
       |awk -F'\x99' 'NR<4{s=s" "$2}END{print "tar xvf foo.tar "s}'
       |sh
```

#### Note:

- The above one-liner assumes that all filenames in the tarball don't contain spaces or other special characters
- The tarball name `foo.tar` is hardcoded., you should replace it by your real tarball
- you can test the cmd without the last pipe: `|sh` it will only output the generated `tar -x` command, if it is fine, you can pipe to `|sh` to do real extraction.